# What does "rcl" in ros2 stand for?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ros2, the C++ include paths is something like:

```
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
```

and the python import looks like:

```
import rclpy
```

What does 'rcl' stand for?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236801/what-does-%22rcl%22-in-ros2-stand-for?/) by [Felix Duvallet](https://answers.ros.org/users/22253/felix-duvallet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2016-06-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would guess ROS Client libraries. As said in their r[eadme file](https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/master/README.md).

---

Originally posted by [Laurens Verhulst](https://answers.ros.org/users/26924/laurens-verhulst/) with karma: 167 on 2016-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4